Moving a class into a module and loading an instance from joblib
I have a class called DiseaseTree defined in a file called diseaseTree.py. I have been using this class for a while. In a different workflow I have generated an instance of this class, and written to file using joblib.
I am now attempting to construct a module, with this code in it.
My directory structure looks like this:
/
  /models
    __init__.py
    models.py
    diseaseTree.py
  /plots
    __init__.py
    plots.py
__init__.py
main.py

In models/init.py I have:
from .models import DatabaseConnector
from .diseaseTree import DiseaseTree

In plots/plots.py, I have:
from models import DatabaseConnector
from models import DiseaseTree
import joblib
with open("/data/projects/classifiers/data/diseaseTree.joblib", "rb") as file:
    mainTree = joblib.load(file)

The imports work. When I attempt to load the joblib file, I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diseaseTree'

As best I can tell, it has something to do with the pickling process when the initial instance of DiseaseTree is dumped to file, but I have no idea how to rectify this. If I specifically add the class to sys.modules, I can fool it, i.e do this:
from models import DiseaseTree
temp_module = types.ModuleType('diseaseTree')
temp_module.DiseaseTree = DiseaseTree
sys.modules['diseaseTree'] = temp_module

and then load the joblib file works. If I have to resort to this every time I want to load that instance of diseaseTree, I don't see the point in putting everything into modules in the first place.
How do I either convert/update the instance stored in the joblib file, or handle this elegantly?

The issue is with the way Python handles module imports and pickling. When you save any instance of a class using joblib, the file stores the module path where the class was originally defined. You will get a ModuleNotFoundError if the path has changed.
I suggest ensuring that the module paths are consistent between saving and loading.
Also try using a fully qualified class name when saving or loading which includes the module name in the path, something like:
when saving:
import joblib
from models.diseaseTree import DiseaseTree

tree = DiseaseTree()
joblib.dump(tree, "/data/projects/classifiers/data/diseaseTree.joblib")

when loading
import joblib
from models.diseaseTree import DiseaseTree

with open("/data/projects/classifiers/data/diseaseTree.joblib", "rb") as file:
    mainTree = joblib.load(file)

if joblib is still causing havic, you can use the dill library since it's more robust when it comes to pickling

Ensuring the modules paths are consistent between saving and loading in the future is excellent advice in hindsight, and something to ensure in the future. I'm somewhat more interested in what I do now, with the instances that I currently have - building this module, incorporating it into the workflow that generates the job files, and regenerating the joblib files is not going to be quick. Is there no way to convert them? I'll dig into dill (thanks for the recommendation) to see if that's something that can do, but that's entirely new to me.
